# Angular Material auto complete not showing up

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular-material

since about 3 days I try to get the [Angular autocomplete](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview) working, but with no success at all. Not even the simple example from the page is working. Now i hope some of you could help me with my problem.

Sadly I don't get any error, stack, or log info from the debugger. At this point I am not sure if my component just don't know the `<mat-autocomplete>` tag or I did something wrong when getting the values for the control.

According to the sample a box should appear with the values to select, but I don't even get the box.

Brief description.
I have a service which will call my api to fetch all values (there aren't that many that I would need a dynamic search) to be displayed on the auto complete. For the start I just want to show all entries.

Versions I am using

```
    "@angular/animations": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "~8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "~8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "8.0.0",
```

Please see [Gist](https://gist.github.com/ChristophvdF/6392a2cb034921ab92ae6b2bc9941e31) for the complete code.

Loading all elements from angular material (material.module.ts) and use them in the app.module.ts.

In my component (add-groceries.component.ts) I load all data I need for the view in the `ngOnInit()` method.

When i open up the view (add-groceries.component.html), and click on the control (foodName) absolutely nothing happens. According to the sample a box should appear which will show the elements to select but not even the box is shown.

Currently I added a filter function to make sure that data is present when I change the value of the input field. Everything is working on this end, when the input has no value the whole list will be assigned to `filteredFood`.

I hope someone here could help me with my problem.

Thx in advance!

Comment: Can you narrow this down to the exact problem you're having - maybe put that up front? I got to the end and am not sure what is not working.

Comment: Sorry, I thing with the thought of providing as much info as possible I wasn't to clear on whats not working. According to the sample when the input gets focus the autocomplete should show a box which contains the elements to pick. That control isn't showing up in any state.

Comment: So, I would reformat the question to provide a minimal, complete example. Show screenshots of what you expect and what is not working. If the code is complicated enough, prepare a stackblitz. In any case, there's too much here to be a useful question in my opinion.

Comment: Thx I will rework the question again. Since I don't know on which part i messed up I thought I show nearly all...

Comment: Yes, and that's an issue- I personally don't have time to narrow down your issue for you. You should do some basic troubleshooting first, then post when you think you've narrowed it down.

Comment: I hope i made the question a bit more clear now. Thx for your suggestions!

Comment: Are you sure your `filteredFood` array has any values? I don't see where it would definitively be set with values in your code.

Comment: Please see add-groceries.component.ts ln: 57. I checked with chrome debugger, values are present.